# Change CSS based on scroll position -- Refactoring bad code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have written a jQuery function that changes the css value of a nav menu item based on if its reference section is viewable in the window.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 590) {
        $("#menu-item-25 a").addClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-26 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-22 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-23 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-24 a").removeClass('blue');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 591 && scroll <= 1380) {
        $("#menu-item-26 a").addClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-25 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-22 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-23 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-24 a").removeClass('blue');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 1381 && scroll <= 2545) {
        $("#menu-item-22 a").addClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-25 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-26 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-23 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-24 a").removeClass('blue');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 2546 && scroll <= 2969) {
        $("#menu-item-23 a").addClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-25 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-26 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-22 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-24 a").removeClass('blue');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 2970) {
        $("#menu-item-24 a").addClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-25 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-26 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-22 a").removeClass('blue');
        $("#menu-item-23 a").removeClass('blue');
    }
});
```

It looks awfully ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Write the adding and removing of classes as a function?

Comment: You should *also* consider [caching the DOM selectors](http://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/) as well - `var menuItem22 = $("#menu-item-22 a")` and then access it like `$(menuItem22).removeClass()` will prevent you from accessing the DOM each time you want to perform an op on the element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the previous answers will work just fine, because you have multiple ways to make this better just making some changes to your CSS selectors, but if you will do all this calculations in the scroll event, you should read this [John Resign Post](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) about how to deal with scroll event, specially this part:

> **It’s a very, very, bad idea** to attach handlers to the window scroll event. Depending upon the browser the scroll event can fire a lot and putting code in the scroll callback will slow down any attempts to scroll the page (not a good idea). Any performance degradation in the scroll handler(s) as a result will only compound the performance of scrolling overall. Instead it’s much better to use some form of a timer to check every X milliseconds OR to attach a scroll event and only run your code after a delay (or even after a given number of executions – and then a delay).
>    - John Resign

So, in your case I would go like this:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a id="menu-item-22">Link 1</a>
    <a id="menu-item-23">Link 2</a>
    <a id="menu-item-24">Link 3</a>
    <a id="menu-item-25">Link 4</a>
    <a id="menu-item-26">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

#### Jquery:

```
var didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        var $el;

        //Same that all the if else statements
        switch (true) {
            case (scroll >= 591 && scroll <= 1380):
                $el = $("#menu-item-26 a");
                break;
            case (scroll >= 1381 && scroll <= 2545):
                $el = $("#menu-item-22 a");
                break;
            case (scroll >= 2546 && scroll <= 2969):
                $el = $("#menu-item-23 a");
                break;
            case (scroll >= 2970):
                $el = $("#menu-item-24 a");
                break;
            default: //scroll<=590
                $el = $("#menu-item-25 a");
        }

        //Removing blue class from all links
        $('.menu a').removeClass('blue');

        //Adding blue class to the matched element
        $el.addClass('blue');
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. I always felt like things got a little jolty when attaching handlers to the scroll event. This looks like a great solution, I will give it a go

Comment: Assuming the elements which you are looking for which match `#menu-item-* a` don't change, this could be further improved by obtaining a reference to each of those by looking through the DOM (i.e. `$('foo')`) only once and assigning each reference to a variable. Those values can then be used repeatedly without the overhead of looking through the DOM each time. Obviously, if the actual elements are being added/removed from the DOM, then you do need to search the DOM for them each time.

Comment: It doesn't matter much but I prefer the timeout approach: `var scrollTO; $(window).scroll(function(){clearTimeout(scrollTO);scrollTO=setTimeout(...,100);});`

Answer (score 1):

You *shouldn't* be accessing a common group of elements using their ID's -

**Example**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a id="menu-item-22 a">Link 1</a>
    <a id="menu-item-23 a">Link 2</a>
    <a id="menu-item-24 a">Link 3</a>
    <a id="menu-item-25 a">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

**1 -** Remove classes from all `<a>`'s in `.menu`

```
$(".menu a").removeClass("blue");
```

**2 -** Display the one you want

```
$("#menu-item-25 a").addClass("red");
```

---

You should *also* consider [caching the DOM selectors](http://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/) -

`var menuItem22 = $("#menu-item-22 a")`

and then access it like:

`$(menuItem22).addClass('red')`

This will prevent you from accessing the DOM each time you want to perform an op on the element. This is not absolutely necessary in your case but it's a good trick to keep in mind

Comment: Thank you! I have refactored the code and it is much cleaner. I've cached the selectors and removed the blue class by selected the group and not the individual elements. Thanks again!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have dynamically appended menu times on runtime - e.g you dynamically insert more `<a>` elements in your menu after you cache them - you need to re-cache them. I doubt that this will be the case though but I'm giving you the heads up anyway

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

http://pastebin.com/SrtE3yxS

```
$(function() {

var highlighted = null,         // Keep track of previously selected
    $menuItems  = $('#menu a'); // Grab all menu items once

// Which items at which points
var breakpoints = {
    '#menu-item-25': 590,
    '#menu-item-26': 1380,
    '#menu-item-22': 2545,
    '#menu-item-23': 2969,
    '#menu-item-24': 99999
};

$(window).scroll(function() {

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        selected = '#menu-item-24';  // default

    // Loop through breakpoints to find the current one that should be selected
    for (id in breakpoints) {
        if (scroll <= breakpoints[id]) {
            selected = id;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the right one is already highlighted, do nothing
    if (highlighted == id) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove all
    $menuItems.removeClass('blue');
    // Add it to the one you need
    $(id).addClass('blue');

});
```

});

Comment: Forgot one thing... below where it sets the class to blue...

highlighted = id;

so that it remembers for next time which is highlighted

Comment: Or... you could get rid of the highlighted variable and do if ($(id).hasClass('blue')) { return; }

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to do the ever same thing..

```
 function menueHandle(ident, color, type){
    for(var i = 0; i < ident.length; i++){
        var handle = $("#menu-item-"+ident[i]+" a");
        if(type == 'remove'){
            handle.removeClass(color);
        }else{
            handle.addClass(color);
        }
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll <= 590) {
    menueHandle([25], 'blue', 'add');
    menueHandle([26,26,22,23, 24], 'blue', 'remove');
}else if (scroll >= 591 && scroll <= 1380) {
    menueHandle([26], 'blue', 'add');
    menueHandle([25,26,22,23, 24], 'blue', 'remove');
}else if (scroll >= 1381 && scroll <= 2545) {
    menueHandle([22], 'blue', 'add');
    menueHandle([25,26,22,23, 24], 'blue', 'remove');
}else if (scroll >= 2546 && scroll <= 2969) {
    menueHandle([23], 'blue', 'add');
    menueHandle([25,26,22,23, 24], 'blue', 'remove');
}else if (scroll >= 2970) {
    menueHandle([24], 'blue', 'add');
    menueHandle([25,26,22,23], 'blue', 'remove');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another approach (my personal favorite)

- Use **`setTimeout()`** for scroll event handling
- Use **`getBoundingClientRect()`** for detecting elements in view

https://codepen.io/oriadam/pen/NLMqjN

```
var vertical_threshold = 3; // pixels inside the element for it to be considered in view

function element_in_view(e) {
    if (e.style.display == "none") {
        // when element is hidden, getBoundingClientRect() returns all 0
        return false;
    }
    var r = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        r.top >= 0 && // vertical check 1
        r.top <=
            (innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) -
                Math.min(r.height, vertical_threshold) // vertical check 2
        /* CHECK HORIZONTAL SCROLL
                && r.left >= 0 // horizontal check 1
                && r.right <= (innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) // horizontal check 2
                */
    );
}

function onScroll() {
    console.log("onScroll");
    $("li").each(function() {
        this.classList.toggle("inview", element_in_view(this));
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(window.scrollTO);
    window.scrollTO = setTimeout(onScroll, 50);
}).trigger('scroll');
```